# Attempting to sort long list into separate columns

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

We currently have a long list of students and we are attempting to sort them into various columns based on year. I am trying to make this as simple as possible so I do not have to rewrite the code for every school year change. The basic way this will work is it should grab the list of students from one Spreadsheet and then return an array of the students based on the year that is passed in as a parameter. Any help would be much appreciated. This is the current code that I have:

```
    function yearSort(gradYearDesired)
    {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var temp =  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName("StudentAccountsImport"));
      var tempArray = [];
      var nameArray = [];
      var outputArray = [];

      var range = temp.getRange("G2:G");
      tempArray.push(range);
      return tempArray;
      var range = temp.getRange("B2:B");
      nameArray.push(range);

      for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
      {
        if(tempArray[i] == gradYearDesired)
        {
          outputArray.push(nameArray[i]);
        }
      }

      return outputArray;
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing what format the list is in, it's hard to tell what's going on here. Also, consider using the built-in `filter` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use query function, no need in script:

```
=query(StudentAccountsImport!B:G, "select B where G = 2016")
```

if this doesn't work, please add more details on where your data is placed.

---

Also possible to use filter:

```
=filter(StudentAccountsImport!B:B, StudentAccountsImport!G:G = 2016)
```

but query gives more options for select.

Comment: In addition to the right suggestion of Max, you can then nest sort(query(...),column, is_ascending).
If you don't want users to modify the formula to provide the date you can concatenate an external cell reference. 
...,"select B where G = "&A1&") where 'A1' contain the year.